# How fix UTF-8 Characters in PHP file_get_contents()

Tags: php, utf-8, file-get-contents

When I am using `file_get_contents($url)`, and when I echo this, it returns an exotic character.

But it can be seen only in some websites and works correctly in other websites:

[image: see picture]

My code is:

```html
<?php
header ( "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8" );
$url ="http://www.varzesh3.com/news/1307290";
echo $go_to = file_get_contents($url);
?>
```

Comment: Make sure that both, the file you are reading and the PHP script that reads it, are UTF-8 encoded (UTF-8 without BOM).

Comment: Sorry but, I did not catch.

Comment: If the file you are reading is already utf-8 encoded you need to convert nothing at all. But the php script must be utf-8 encoded too. Otherwise it does not handle the file contents correctly. You can change the encoding of the script file by a couple of editors. One of them is Notepad++.

Comment: Plus: functions like _mb\_convert\_encoding_ are **converting** characters into utf-8. If the original file does not contain utf-8 characters the script can not create them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to PHP manual:

you can use this code, if you have problem with file_get_contents!

```
<?php
function file_get_contents_utf8($fn) {
     $content = file_get_contents($fn);
      return mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8',
          mb_detect_encoding($content, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true));
}
?>
```

Comment: hmmm, now try this : `$result = mb_convert_encoding($last_file, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");`

Comment: oh my god, Sorry my friend but This is not. for sample url test this link : http://www.varzesh3.com/news/1307397/

Comment: i want recive "http://www.varzesh3.com/news/1307397/" html codes. but when i use [ file_get_contents ]  and echo this cant view then.This site does not display a code that allows..

Comment: please try `$content = @file_get_contents($fn);` then if not work , we can make decision

Comment: no no no Sorry, Please test yourself. echo file_get_contents(http://www.varzesh3.com/news/1307397/%22);

Comment: you must act like this : `echo file_get_contents(http://www.varzesh3.com/news/1307397/%22); `

Answer (score 0):

and set header, it need to be first witch php send to client browser

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset =utf-8');
```