# File get contents retrieve question diamonds characters

Tags: php, html, file, character-encoding, file-get-contents

I've created my crawler using `file_get_contents` function but when I crawl some sites I'm getting this character: � when I should get this: é. Some ideas of what is happening?

This is for a windows vps server running php.

I've already tried:

- [file_get_contents() Breaks Up UTF-8 Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236668/file-get-contents-breaks-up-utf-8-characters)
- [How fix UTF-8 Characters in PHP file_get_contents()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35679900/how-fix-utf-8-characters-in-php-file-get-contents)
- [How to get file content with a proper utf-8 encoding using file_get_contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47377098/how-to-get-file-content-with-a-proper-utf-8-encoding-using-file-get-contents)

But all these things didn't work.

**PD**: My file where I'm running this code is on UTF8.

```
    $url = "https://play.google.com/books/reader?id=4rqYDwAAQBAJ&hl=en_US";
    $options = array('http'=>array('method'=>"GET", 'header'=>"Accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8\r\n" ."Accept-Charset: UTF-8, *;q=0"));
            $context = stream_context_create($options)
            $profile = file_get_contents($url,false,$context);
echo $profile
```

I'm expecting to get accented characters and not this diamond character �.

Comment: If you read the question are not the same!

Comment: In what format was your php file saved as? exactly though.

Comment: All as UTF8 encoding @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: Ok. But UTF8 has 2 methods to save as. With or without BOM (byte order mark) which might make a difference.

Comment: Without BOM. @FunkFortyNiner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google is ignoring your *Accept-Charset* header because you're not specifying a User-Agent, no idea why. It took me one hour to figure it out. Adjust your options as follows:

```
$options = [
    "http" => [
        "method" => "GET",
        "header" => "Accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8\\r\n" .
                    "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0\r\n" .
                    "Accept-Charset: UTF-8, *;q=0"
              ]
];
```

Adding the "User-Agent" header seems to do the trick. Google is probably returning a different encoding if not.